# All combinations of values from two lists representing a certain feature

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

I have three lists:

```
a = [0,1,2]
b = [3,4,5]
c = [aab, abb, aaa]
```

How to create all three-element combinations? Where sequences from the list `c` tell you which list can be used to choose numbers for a given place in a given output sequence

For example (pseudocode):

```
for i=0 in range(len(c)):
    print: [0,1,3]
           [0,1,4]
             ...
           [0,2,5]
             ...
           [1,2,4]
           [1,2,5]
```

And the same for the rest of the `i` indexes. Where the values in individual sublistas can not be repeated.
I will be very grateful for any tips.

Comment: What are ""How to create all three-element combinations?"" Can you illustrate more?

Comment: And that doesn't look like Python. More importantly, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I deliberately used pseudo-language to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I used it as a standard `it.combinations`, and later screening conditions. but I wanted to find an approach that would not look for all combinations with each index.

Comment: """Where the values in individual sublistas can not be repeated.""" explanation to this line?

Comment: Are the `ab` patterns always in alphabetical order? Are the `a` and `b` lists guaranteed to be disjoint, i.e. no element of `a` is in `b` or vice versa?

Comment: not always. and they are always separate.

Comment: For the pattern `'aab'` should the results contain both `[0,1,3]` and `[1,0,3]` or just one of them?

Comment: @wwii yes both :)

Comment: but for example for the formula 'aaa' one combination from of the pairs [0,1,2] and [2,1,0] must be removed.

Comment: So, how many items does `'aaa'` produce?  Please include in your question the (complete) expected results for the patterns `'aaa'` and `'abb'`.

Comment: for 'aaa' should be [0,1,2], [0,2,1], [1,0,2]. and 'abb' should be [0,3,4],[0,4,3],[0,3,5],[0,5,3],[0,4,5],[0,5,4] and the same with 1 and 2 in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generator function will handle 'ab' template strings with the a's and b's in any order, and the output lists will not contain repeated items if the `a` and `b` lists are disjoint. We use `itertools.combinations` to generate combinations of the required order, and combine the `a` and `b` combinations using `itertools.product`. We get them in the correct order by turning each `a` and `b` combination into an iterator and select from the correct iterator via a dictionary.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def groups(a, b, c):
    for pat in c:
        acombo = combinations(a, pat.count('a'))
        bcombo = combinations(b, pat.count('b'))
        for ta, tb in product(acombo, bcombo):
            d = {'a': iter(ta), 'b': iter(tb)}
            yield [next(d[k]) for k in pat]

# tests

a = [0,1,2]
b = [3,4,5]

templates = ['aab', 'abb', 'aaa'], ['aba'], ['bab']

for c in templates:
    print('c', c)
    for i, t in enumerate(groups(a, b, c), 1):
        print(i, t)
    print()
```

**output**

```
c ['aab', 'abb', 'aaa']
1 [0, 1, 3]
2 [0, 1, 4]
3 [0, 1, 5]
4 [0, 2, 3]
5 [0, 2, 4]
6 [0, 2, 5]
7 [1, 2, 3]
8 [1, 2, 4]
9 [1, 2, 5]
10 [0, 3, 4]
11 [0, 3, 5]
12 [0, 4, 5]
13 [1, 3, 4]
14 [1, 3, 5]
15 [1, 4, 5]
16 [2, 3, 4]
17 [2, 3, 5]
18 [2, 4, 5]
19 [0, 1, 2]

c ['aba']
1 [0, 3, 1]
2 [0, 4, 1]
3 [0, 5, 1]
4 [0, 3, 2]
5 [0, 4, 2]
6 [0, 5, 2]
7 [1, 3, 2]
8 [1, 4, 2]
9 [1, 5, 2]

c ['bab']
1 [3, 0, 4]
2 [3, 0, 5]
3 [4, 0, 5]
4 [3, 1, 4]
5 [3, 1, 5]
6 [4, 1, 5]
7 [3, 2, 4]
8 [3, 2, 5]
9 [4, 2, 5]
```

I should mention that even though `combinations` returns iterators, and `product` happily takes iterators as arguments, it has to make lists from the iterators because it has to run over the iterator contents multiple times. So if the number of combinations is huge this can consume a fair amount of RAM.

---

If you want permutations instead of combinations, that's easy. We just call `itertools.permutations` instead of `itertools.combinations`.

```
from itertools import permutations, product

def groups(a, b, c):
    for pat in c:
        acombo = permutations(a, pat.count('a'))
        bcombo = permutations(b, pat.count('b'))
        for ta, tb in product(acombo, bcombo):
            d = {'a': iter(ta), 'b': iter(tb)}
            yield [next(d[k]) for k in pat]

# tests

a = [0,1,2]
b = [3,4,5]

templates = ['aaa'], ['abb'] 

for c in templates:
    print('c', c)
    for i, t in enumerate(groups(a, b, c), 1):
        print(i, t)
    print()
```

**output**

```
 c ['aaa']
1 [0, 1, 2]
2 [0, 2, 1]
3 [1, 0, 2]
4 [1, 2, 0]
5 [2, 0, 1]
6 [2, 1, 0]

c ['abb']
1 [0, 3, 4]
2 [0, 3, 5]
3 [0, 4, 3]
4 [0, 4, 5]
5 [0, 5, 3]
6 [0, 5, 4]
7 [1, 3, 4]
8 [1, 3, 5]
9 [1, 4, 3]
10 [1, 4, 5]
11 [1, 5, 3]
12 [1, 5, 4]
13 [2, 3, 4]
14 [2, 3, 5]
15 [2, 4, 3]
16 [2, 4, 5]
17 [2, 5, 3]
18 [2, 5, 4]
```

---

Finally, here's a version that handles any number of lists, and template strings of any length. It only accepts a single template string per call, but that shouldn't be an issue. You can also choose whether you want to generate permutations or combinations via an optional keyword arg.

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, product

def groups(sources, template, mode='P'):
    func = permutations if mode == 'P' else combinations
    keys = sources.keys()
    combos = [func(sources[k], template.count(k)) for k in keys]
    for t in product(*combos):
        d = {k: iter(v) for k, v in zip(keys, t)}
        yield [next(d[k]) for k in template]

# tests

sources = {
    'a': [0, 1, 2],
    'b': [3, 4, 5],
    'c': [6, 7, 8],
}

templates = 'aa', 'abc', 'abba', 'cab'

for template in templates:
    print('\ntemplate', template)
    for i, t in enumerate(groups(sources, template, mode='C'), 1):
        print(i, t)
```

**output**

```
template aa
1 [0, 1]
2 [0, 2]
3 [1, 2]

template abc
1 [0, 3, 6]
2 [0, 3, 7]
3 [0, 3, 8]
4 [0, 4, 6]
5 [0, 4, 7]
6 [0, 4, 8]
7 [0, 5, 6]
8 [0, 5, 7]
9 [0, 5, 8]
10 [1, 3, 6]
11 [1, 3, 7]
12 [1, 3, 8]
13 [1, 4, 6]
14 [1, 4, 7]
15 [1, 4, 8]
16 [1, 5, 6]
17 [1, 5, 7]
18 [1, 5, 8]
19 [2, 3, 6]
20 [2, 3, 7]
21 [2, 3, 8]
22 [2, 4, 6]
23 [2, 4, 7]
24 [2, 4, 8]
25 [2, 5, 6]
26 [2, 5, 7]
27 [2, 5, 8]

template abba
1 [0, 3, 4, 1]
2 [0, 3, 5, 1]
3 [0, 4, 5, 1]
4 [0, 3, 4, 2]
5 [0, 3, 5, 2]
6 [0, 4, 5, 2]
7 [1, 3, 4, 2]
8 [1, 3, 5, 2]
9 [1, 4, 5, 2]

template cab
1 [6, 0, 3]
2 [7, 0, 3]
3 [8, 0, 3]
4 [6, 0, 4]
5 [7, 0, 4]
6 [8, 0, 4]
7 [6, 0, 5]
8 [7, 0, 5]
9 [8, 0, 5]
10 [6, 1, 3]
11 [7, 1, 3]
12 [8, 1, 3]
13 [6, 1, 4]
14 [7, 1, 4]
15 [8, 1, 4]
16 [6, 1, 5]
17 [7, 1, 5]
18 [8, 1, 5]
19 [6, 2, 3]
20 [7, 2, 3]
21 [8, 2, 3]
22 [6, 2, 4]
23 [7, 2, 4]
24 [8, 2, 4]
25 [6, 2, 5]
26 [7, 2, 5]
27 [8, 2, 5]
```

Comment: well, this stupid RAM;) that's why I'm constantly trying to write something without storing it in my memory. but a hard thing :) thanks for your solution. for now, I am testing the solution of colleague @wwii. but strangely when it comes to calculating time it comes out worse than in my old solution ...

Comment: why in your solution if I want to make only one 'templates' value then I have to enter it with a comma? that is, for example, `templates = ['bba'],`. Because otherwise it displays results incorrectly.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski `for c in templates:` loops over a collection of templates. The line `templates = ['bba'],` creates a 1 item tuple that contains the 1 item list `['bba']`. (Parentheses don't create tuples, commas do). You could just do `a = [0,1,2]; b = [3,4,5]; c = ['bba']` `
for i, t in enumerate(groups(a, b, c), 1): print(i, t)`

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski As you noticed, wwii's solution makes a high proportion of combinations containing repeated elements. And then you have to filter those out, so it's bound to be slower than a solution like mine which simply avoids making combinations containing repeated elements.

Comment: I've just tested. in fact your solution is the fastest! thanks!

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski No worries. It's an interesting problem. Now I'm tempted to make a more general version that can handle any number of source lists, not just two. :)

Comment: indeed, a general solution would be interesting, because then, for example, you could extend the characteristics of the `c` list to other combinations :) I will think about it myself, but if you can also generalize the above solution, let me know :) best regards!

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski See if you can adapt my code to a general solution, and if you get stuck, ask a new question, linking to this one. You should build a list or dict to store the combinations instead having separate named combinations like `acombo` and `bcombo`.

Comment: I worked out (what I think) is a generic version of this then I noticed that my filtered solution has more *results* than your solution ... for the pattern `'abb'` mine produces `(0,3,4)` and `(0,4,3)` so mine has twice as many tuples and for `'aaa'` I get six tuples instead of one. ??  I'll ask OP.

Comment: @wwii From the partial output shown in the question, I'm pretty sure that the OP wants combinations, not permutations, so it should only produce one of (0,3,4) and (0,4,3).

Comment: indeed, some results are missing, for example, for the formula 'aaa' should be [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2].

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Seriously? Next time, you should do a better job of showing / describing the expected output! So why does 'aaa' give just those 3 permutations and not `[1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]` as well?

Comment: that's what it should be for 'aaa'. my mistake. I wanted to save some time on accurate explanations and these are the effects. sorry.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Ok. In that case, it's _very_ easy to modify my code to give all those permutations. Give me a minute or two...

Comment: hehe one more small thing. and you can somehow implement something like `[v for k, v in enumerate (a) if v [:: - 1] not in a [: k]]`, that only 3 results for 'aaa', means without reflections. ?

Comment: although there are few such results in relation to everyone, it may not even be worth it;)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski A simple way to eliminate reflections is to use a set. Like this: `out = set()` `for t in groups(a, b, c):` `if t[::-1] not in out:` `out.add(t)`. Of course, a set doesn't preserve order, so you may then want to do `for i, t in enumerate(sorted(out), 1): print(i, t)`

Comment: I have one more request. how to transform a function in the general case to work on 'a1a3a2' strings? not 'abc'. because then there is an error in the line: `yield [next(d[k]) for k in template]`.

Comment: @Tomasz I don't understand that string. You should ask a new question and link it to this one.

Comment: the point is that now your string understands strings like 'aab', 'bca' etc. But I tried to replace `a, b, c ...` with `a1, a2, a3 ...` and with this type of variables it is already problem. but I will fight again. and if I can not do it then I will ask the official question :)

Comment: However, I'm stuck with this iteration, I put a new question with a link to your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139438/iterating-after-pairs-in-string-in-python

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product, chain

setups = ['aab', 'abb', 'aaa']
sources = {
    'a': [0,1,2],
    'b': [3,4,5]
}

combinations = (product(*map(sources.get, setup)) for setup in setups)
```

`combinations` is a nested lazy iterator (i.e. nothing is stored in memory and calculated, yet). If you want to get an iterator of lists

```
combinations = map(list, (product(*map(sources.get, setup)) for setup in setups))
```

Or you might want to flatten the result:

```
combinations = chain.from_iterable(product(*map(sources.get, setup)) for setup in setups)
```

Comment: This code produces lots of lists that contain repeated items, which the OP doesn't want. You _could_ just filter them out, but that is rather inefficient if the source lists and setups strings are large.

Comment: @PM2Ring then I guess, I misunderstood the task.

Comment: but it was close :) because I'm interested in the most economical way, because I work on large lists. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Put the lists in a dictionary so you can access them with strings.
Use the characters in each sequence to determine which lists to use.
Use itertools.product to get the *combinations*.

```
import itertools, collections
from pprint import pprint
d = {'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3,4,5]}
c = ['aab', 'abb', 'aaa']

def f(t):
    t = collections.Counter(t)
    return max(t.values()) < 2

for seq in c:
    data = (d[char] for char in seq)
    print(f'sequence: {seq}')
    pprint(list(filter(f, itertools.product(*data))))
    print('***************************')
```

Result for sequence `'abb'`:

```
sequence: abb
[(0, 3, 4),
 (0, 3, 5),
 (0, 4, 3),
 (0, 4, 5),
 (0, 5, 3),
 (0, 5, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (1, 4, 3),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (1, 5, 3),
 (1, 5, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 4, 3),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (2, 5, 3),
 (2, 5, 4)]
```

---

edit to filter out tuples with *duplicates*

---

I like the idea of a callable dict that can be used with map.  It could be used here.

```
class CallDict(dict):
    def __call__(self, key):
        return self[key]    #self.get(key)

e = CallDict([('a',[0,1,2]), ('b',[3,4,5])])

for seq in c:
    data = map(e, seq)
    print(f'sequence: {seq}')
    for thing in filter(f, itertools.product(*data)):
        print(thing)
    print('***************************')
```

---

I couldn't help myself, here is a *generic* version of @PM2Ring's [solution/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121777/2823755). Instead of filtering out unwanted items, it doesn't produce them in the first place.

```
d = {'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3,4,5]}
c = ['aab', 'abb', 'aaa', 'aba']
def g(d, c):
    for seq in c:
        print(f'sequence: {seq}')
        counts = collections.Counter(seq)
##        data = (itertools.combinations(d[key],r) for key, r in counts.items())
        data = (itertools.permutations(d[key],r) for key, r in counts.items())
        for thing in itertools.product(*data):
            q = {key:iter(other) for key, other in zip(counts, thing)}
            yield [next(q[k]) for k in seq]

for t in g(d, c):
    print(t)
```

Comment: it seems fine, just to set the filter so that there are no duplicate values in a given tuple.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski - Are tuples with duplicate values *discarded*?

Comment: yes, I said a little badly  :) I used your solution for now, but I was a bit surprised because it turned out to be longer in time. honestly, looking at the code itself, I expected to shorten the time. sigh ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you can achieve the goal with a dictionary bookkeeping the correspondence of a character like `"a"` to a variable name `a`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [0,1,2]
b = [3,4,5]
c = ["aab", "abb", "aaa"]
d = {"a": a, "b": b}
d2 = defaultdict(list)
for seq in c:
    l = []
    for idx, v in enumerate(seq):
        l.append(d[v][idx]) 
    print(l)
    d2[seq].append(l)
# Out:
#[0, 1, 5]
#[0, 4, 5]
#[0, 1, 2]
print(d2)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aab': [[0, 1, 5]], 'abb': [[0, 4, 5]], 'aaa': [[0, 1, 2]]})
```

Comment: near. and how do you get all the combinations with a given feature?

Comment: What is a given feature? @TomaszPrzemski

Comment: all with characteristics 'aab', all with characteristics 'abb', all with characteristics 'aaa'

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Updated. Is this what you mean? Keep another dictionary that stores the value each time a sequence is formed.

Comment: it was not what it was about yet, but I already have a solution. though not perfect :) thanks for your time!

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski No problem. Best

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for some way to programmatically call [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#product)

```
from itertools import product

d = {'a': [0,1,2],
     'b': [3,4,5]}
c = ['aab', 'abb', 'aaa']

for s in c:
    print(list(product(*[d[x] for x in s])))
```