# Several similar regexes. Faster way to do this?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, performance

I have a rather simple set of requirements.  I have a list (of length 2 million) of objects, each with 2 properties that need to be regexed (other properties are not changed)

Values of ZERO ONE TWO ... TEN need to be changed to their numeric value: 1 2 ... 10

Examples:

```
ONE MAIN STREET -> 1 MAIN STREET
BONE ROAD -> BONE ROAD
BUILDING TWO, THREE MAIN ROAD -> BUILDING 2, 3 MAIN ROAD
ELEVEN MAIN ST -> ELEVEN MAIN STREET
ONE HUNDRED FUNTOWN -> 1 HUNDRED FUNTOWN
```

Clearly are some numbers that do not get changed and some charged oddly.  **that is completely expected**

I can get it all to work with what I have below.  My question is, is there a clever way to make this all run faster?  I've thought of making an `list` of `dictionaries` where the keys are the word-numbers and values are numeric, but I don't think that will help with performance.  Or `re.compile` each regex and pass them into this function?  Any clever idea out there to make this run faster?

```
def update_word_to_numeric(entrylist):
    updated_entrylist = []
    for theentry in entrylist:
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bZERO\b", "0", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bONE\b", "1", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bTWO\b", "2", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bTHREE\b", "3", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bFOUR\b", "4", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bFIVE\b", "5", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bSIX\b", "6", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bSEVEN\b", "7", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bEIGHT\b", "8", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bNINE\b", "9", theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"\bTEN\b", "10", theentry.addr_ln_1)

        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bZERO\b", "0", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bONE\b", "1", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bTWO\b", "2", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bTHREE\b", "3", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bFOUR\b", "4", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bFIVE\b", "5", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bSIX\b", "6", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bSEVEN\b", "7", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bEIGHT\b", "8", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bNINE\b", "9", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"\bTEN\b", "10", theentry.addr_ln_2)
        updated_entrylist.append(theentry)
    return updated_entrylist
```

Maybe this is just a fine way to do it.  Comments of "that's good enough" are good with me too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much faster to use one regular expression instead of ten (I noticed a 3x increase in speed):

```
def replace(match):
    return {
        "ZERO": "0",
        "ONE": "1",
        "TWO": "2",
        "THREE": "3",
        "FOUR": "4",
        "FIVE": "5",
        "SIX": "6",
        "SEVEN": "7",
        "EIGHT": "8",
        "NINE": "9",
        "TEN": "10",
    }[match.group(1)]

pattern = re.compile(r"\b(ZERO|ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN)\b")

def update_word_to_numeric(entrylist):
    updated_entrylist = []
    for theentry in entrylist:
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = pattern.sub(replace, theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = pattern.sub(replace, theentry.addr_ln_2)
        updated_entrylist.append(theentry)
    return updated_entrylist
```

I'm using the little-known functionality to hand `re.sub` a function as the second argument: It will take a match object and return the replacement string. That way we can look up the replacement string.

I also used `re.compile` to precompile the regex, this also improved the time, but not as much as the big change.

Comment: Sometimes I like the idea of a [callable dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121349/2823755)

Comment: @wwii Sadly, this won't work here, because we get the match object as an input, not a string.

Comment: I like how readable this is.  Should I rename the `def replace` to something like `def replace_number`?  Just thinking about how `replace` is a term used in Python.  Or does it have to be replace?

Comment: This is great, the process was 45 seconds my old way, down to 3 seconds.  Perfect.

Comment: @sniperd Great to hear! It doesn't have to be `replace`, of course, name it how you want. It won't collide with `str.replace` though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using a dictionary:

```
s = '''
ONE MAIN STREET
BONE ROAD
BUILDING TWO, THREE MAIN ROAD
ELEVEN MAIN ST
ONE HUNDRED FUNTOWN
'''

d = {'ZERO':'0', 'ONE':'1', 'TWO':'2', 'THREE':'3', 'FOUR':'4', 
     'FIVE':'5', 'SIX':'6', 'SEVEN':'7', 'EIGHT':'8', 'NINE':'9', 
     'TEN':'10', 'ELEVEN':'11', 'TWELVE':'12'}

p = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
r = p.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)

print(r)
```

Add or remove entries from the dictionary as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = ["\bZERO\b", "\bONE\b", "\bTWO\b", "\bTHREE\b", "\bFOUR\b", "\bFIVE\b", "\bSIX\b", "\bSEVEN\b", "\bEIGHT\b", "\bNINE\b", "\bTEN\b"]
for theentry in entrylist:
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        theentry.addr_ln_1 = re.sub(r"{}".format(number), "{}".format(i), theentry.addr_ln_1)
        theentry.addr_ln_2 = re.sub(r"{}".format(number), "{}".format(i), theentry.addr_ln_2)
```